# Error Propagation through R2 score

Tags: regression, error-propagation

The $R^2$ score is defined by:

$$R^2 = 1 - \dfrac{SS_{res}}{SS_{tot}} = 1 - \dfrac{\sum (f_i-y_i)^2}{\sum (y_i - \bar{y})^2}$$

for my fitted values $f_i$ from my model I have error estimates $\sigma_{f_i}$, I want to propagate these through to get an estimate in the error for $R^2$. Using approximate error propagation:

$$\sigma_{R^2}^2 = R^2 \bigg [ \bigg(\dfrac{\sigma_{SS_{res}}}{SS_{res}}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\dfrac{\sigma_{SS_{tot}}}{SS_{tot}}\bigg)^2 -2 \bigg(\dfrac{\sigma_{SS_{res}SS_{tot}}}{SS_{res}SS_{tot}}\bigg)\bigg] $$

I can get $\sigma_{SS_{res}}^2$ as:

$$\sigma_{SS_{res}}^2 = 4 \sum (f_i-y_i)^2 \sigma_{f_i}^2$$

Do I need to propagate the standard deviation of the mean $\bar{y}$ or how to get the covariance if I need to consider the deviation of the mean.

Is the $R^2$ score the correct metric to be looking at or is there something better in the case we want to look at the errors? Should I use a weighted $R^2$ score and forgo looking at error propagation?